# Why gRPC C++ client doesn't work without explicit server's SSL certificate, like in samples?

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc

The only way right now for me to make SSL encrypted server and client work is to provide the client explicitly with server's certificate. How do I make the server provide its certificate to the client without directly setting it in client's code ?

I am using C++ gRPC. When I create gRPC server, I set its self-signed certificate and private key:

```
 grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions sslServerOptions;
 grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair pkcp;
 pkcp.private_key = serverPrivateKey;
 pkcp.cert_chain  = serverCertChain;
 sslServerOptions.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back( pkcp );
 sslServerOptions.pem_root_certs = “”;
 grpc::SslServerCredentials( sslServerOptions );
```

On the client side if I explicitly set pem_root_certs to server’s certificate – it works fine

```
grpc::SslCredentialsOptions sslChannelOptions;
sslChannelOptions.pem_root_certs  = serverCertChain;
sslChannelOptions.pem_cert_chain  = “”;
sslChannelOptions.pem_private_key = “”;
grpc::SslCredentials( sslChannelOptions );
```

But if I use the code from GRPC samples:

```
 grpc::SslCredentials( grpc::SslCredentialsOptions() );
```

I get this error:

```
E0520 15:24:31.189310128   17046 ssl_transport_security.c:921] Handshake 
failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL 
routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
Translate to Communication exception: Exception encountered while 
receiving response from localhost:10000, with status 14, message: Connect 
Failed
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "Exception encountered while receiving 
response from localhost:10000, with status 14, message: Connect Failed" 
thrown in the test body.
```

Here is how I create SSL keys:

```
    openssl req -new -key server.key -out server_selfsigned.csr 
    "/O=MyCompany/CN=localhost"

    openssl x509 -req -days 1825 -in server_selfsigned.csr -signkey 
    server.key -set_serial 02 -out server_selfsigned.pem
```

My question: why client doesn’t work without explicit server’s certificate ? Thanks !

Comment: Because you are using a self-signed certificate. If you used a CA-signed certificate and the CA is trusted it should work.

Comment: Is there a way to skip it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with C++ but -- eye-balling your code -- I suspect that:

- you must provide the server's cert to the client so that it may authenticate.
- the sample `grpc::SslCredentialsOptions()` corresponds to Go's `grpc.WithInsecure()`. If correct, this approach does not use TLS.

I think you're referring to this:
https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#using-client-side-ssl-tls

Comment: Exactly my point! In the article "Authentication gRPC" they say: This is the simplest authentication scenario, where a client just wants to authenticate the server and encrypt all data:

Comment: auto channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(grpc::SslCredentialsOptions());

Comment: auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(server_name, channel_creds);

Comment: std::unique_ptr<Greeter::Stub> stub(Greeter::NewStub(channel));

Comment: grpc::Status s = stub->sayHello(&context, *request, response);

Comment: I am doing exactly the same - and getting CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED. The client should get the certificate from the server automatically, right ?

Comment: I think: 1. You can use TLS and the client needs the server's cert; 2. No TLS and then neither side uses certs (In Go this is `withInsecure()`. 3. Google OAuth tokens. If I understand the history, an early retirement for TLS over http/2 was relaxed. The documentation may incorrectly reflect this.

Comment: So, you think their sample is obsolete and doesn't work anymore ?